# Equality of first-order partial derivatives

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $f(u,v)$ be a "sufficiently good" function of two variables.

I need to find sufficient conditions on $f$ such that

$$
\frac{\partial f(u,v)}{\partial u}=\frac{\partial f(u,v)}{\partial v},\qquad \forall \,u,v.
$$

For example, if $f(u,v)=f(c(u+v))$ the two first-order partial derivatives coincide. Is this true also in other cases?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain what you mean by "other cases".  However, any solution of the partial differential equation $\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}= \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}$ is of the form $f(u, v)= g(u+ v)$ where g is an arbitrary differentiable function  of a single variable.

Comment: Thank you. I mean if f(u,v)=g(u+v) is the only solution.